# how to get tsclean working on data frame with multiple time series

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I'm in the process of creating a forecast based on the hts package but before getting this far I need to clean the data for outliers and missing values.

For this I thought of using the tsclean function in the forecast package. I got my data stored in data frame with multiple columns (time series) that I wish to get cleaned. I can get the function to work when only having one time serie, but since I do have quite a lot i'm looking for a smart way to do this.

When running the code:

```
SFA5 <- ts(SFA4, frequency=12, start=c(2012,1), end=c(2017,10)) 
ggt <- tsclean(SFA5[1:70, 1:94], replace.missing = TRUE)
```

I get this error message:

```
Error in na.interp(x, lambda = lambda) : The time series is not univariate.
```

The data is here:

```
https://www.dropbox.com/s/dow2jpuv5unmtgd/Data1850.xlsx?dl=0
```

My question is: what am i doing wrong or is the only solution to do a loop sequence

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message suggests that the function takes univariate time series as its first argument only. So you need to apply `tsclean` to each column, as you might have guessed.

```
library(forecast)
ggt <- sapply(X = SFA5[1:70, 1:94], FUN = tsclean)
```

Comment: thank you for your assistance. I'm pretty new to R, so that really did help me from doing a lot of "looping" :-)

Comment: You're welcome. For this kind of tasks you might also want to read this great post about the `apply` family [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505701/grouping-functions-tapply-by-aggregate-and-the-apply-family/7141669). And also check out the `map` functions from the `purrr` package.

Comment: perfect. Thank you for the references.